# Redis ZRANGEBYLEX Escape Characters

Tags: autocomplete, redis

I have few items in my sorted set that look this way:

```
> zrangebylex search - +
1) "abcdefghijkl"
2) "[asd](asd)"
3) "[zxy](zxc)"
```

How can i retrieve the second item only using the the first two characters '[a' ?

I am trying to implement an auto-complete system and these special characters are posing a problem when i tried them in redis-cli.

I have tried the following commands but they don't work (with/without quotes) :

```
zrangebylex search ([a "([a\xff"
zrangebylex search (\[a "([a\xff"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

redis-cli needs the quotes, but other than that all should be working as expected. Here's the output of my session:

```
127.0.0.1:6379> zadd search 0 abcdefjhijkl
(integer) 1
127.0.0.1:6379> zadd search 0 "[asd](asd)"
(integer) 1
127.0.0.1:6379> zadd search 0 "[zxy](zxc)"
(integer) 1
127.0.0.1:6379> ZRANGEBYLEX search - +
1) "[asd](asd)"
2) "[zxy](zxc)"
3) "abcdefjhijkl"
127.0.0.1:6379> ZRANGEBYLEX search "([a" "([a\xff"
1) "[asd](asd)"
```

```

Comment: If I then add zadd search 0 "{\"Id\": 14,\"SubId\": 21055,\"CreateDate\": \"2016-04-19T04:16:34.837\Local:0>"}"
May i know how to use ZRANGEBYLEX to search for this specific data?

Comment: Sounds like a different question, but what do you want to search for/by?

Comment: My sorted set has a lot of json string which might look like 
 1) {"Id": 14,"SubId": 21055}
 2) {"Id": 15,"SubId": 21056}
 3) {"Id": 15,"SubId": 21056}
I would like to search for {"Id": 14, Possible??
As i might have different Id.

Comment: Please open a new question with all the relevant details. I promise I'll help there ;)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36745992/redis-zrangebylex-json-string-pattern